# visual studio 2008 localhost URL

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

everytime I try debug my website I press the F5 key. It will always start with this address

```
http://localhost:xxxxx/Default.aspx
```

but the website wont run unless I change the localhost to 127.0.0.1. How do I allow it to run even though it is localhost without having to specify the URL in my project properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add localhost 127.0.0.1 to your hosts file ref http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/

Comment: I uncomment the line localhost 127.0.0.1 but when I debug my program it stills show "Connection to 127.0.0.1 Failed"

Comment: ping localhost and see what you get, ref https://superuser.com/questions/377634/how-can-i-make-localhost-resolve-to-127-0-0-1-instead-of-1

Comment: I get "Reply from 127.0.0.1" when ping 127.0.0.1 and "Reply from ::1:" when ping localhost. Basically I just want my project to debug given the ip addr using localhost so I do not need to always change to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Okay, I don't know what the answer is, but it has to do with ip version 6. (ipv6) Did you try commenting out the "localhost ::1" line in the hosts file? Here is an article about how other people are dealing with the issue: http://www.victor-ratajczyk.com/post/2012/02/25/mysql-fails-to-resolve-localhost-disable-ipv6-on-windows.aspx